# Android complex Recyclerview case

Tags: android, kotlin

in android app written in kotlin, I have recyclerView with adapter that's called HomeAdapter with different view types. From one homepage API call I get items. Every item is maped in class HomeItem and saved into list. Now I normaly use the list in adapter to preview it. My whole homepage activity is one huuuge recyclerview with different types.

Right now I have a requirement. I need to take New items from NewItems API call. These items can not be mapped in HomeItem class (like all items that I use in the adapter and that have defined different view types) because they have different fields.

I must preview these items from NewItems API call in recyclerView and put them on the second place in order on my HomePage. So it should go like this:

- first view type elements from homepage API call
- items from NewItems API call in recyclerview (recycler in recycler situation I guess)
- all the other view types from homepage API call

I am brainstorming this, but it is hard to find any elegant solution for this at the moment. Does anyone has any good idea?

Answer (score 1):

`Adapters` should adapt 1 `List` of data, a different `viewType` dictates how that data is presented. Even a `viewType` that divides the data in alphabetical order is still working with the same `List` of data. If your new API results in objects that aren't compatible with that data, ie interface or abstraction, they don't belong in that `Adapter`, ie in that `RecyclerView`. If the data doesn't belong to a specific `HomeItem` in the `List` then a `RecyclerView` in `RecyclerView` approach wont work either.

For example you have a `List` of items on a menu at a Steakhouse. Your food consists of Name, Description, Ingredients, and Price. This works for all food types Steak, Coke, Fries, etc...

Now looking at your problem, where does the a Weather report fit into your Steakhouse menu? What is the price of a Tornado? Why would completely different Items be inside the same `List`?

That is an extreme case but you may just have an abstraction problem. Meaning `HomeItem` doesn't have enough fields to represent the data for that `Adapter`.

That being said you can get around this by using a `Map`, By adding a `Map` to the `HomeItem` you can then put whatever fields you want in it. Your new `ViewHolder` that represents the new data will simply pull from the map what it wants to display. Doing so won't effect the other implementations of `HomeItem` much at all.